# XNA Pong collision

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, pong

I am making a pong game in XNA and i ran into a problem with the ball-paddle collision.
The side of the paddle is working correctly but the top and bottom are actring weird. I have tried a lot of things but it still doesn't work.
This is my current code:

```
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            //Intersection
            if (bPos.Intersects(p1Pos))
            {
                //top

                //bottom

                //middle
                if (bPos.X <= p1Pos.X + p1Pos.Width)
                    bSpd.X = -bSpd.X;
            }
            if (bPos.Intersects(p2Pos))
            {
                //top

                //bottom

                //middle
                if (bPos.X + bPos.Width >= p2Pos.X)
                    bSpd.X = -bSpd.X;
            }

            bPos.X = bPos.X + (int)bSpd.X;
            bPos.Y = bPos.Y + (int)bSpd.Y;

            if (bPos.Intersects(p1Pos))
            {
                //top

                //bottom

                //middle
                if (bPos.X <= p1Pos.X + p1Pos.Width)
                    bSpd.X = -bSpd.X;
            }
            if (bPos.Intersects(p2Pos))
            {
                //top

                //bottom

                //middle
                if (bPos.X + bPos.Width >= p2Pos.X)
                    bSpd.X = -bSpd.X;
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

Comment: Please narrow your issues down to a few lines...

Comment: Less code now so easier to read

Answer (score 0):

I can just assume some properties about your program.
When you call:

```
bPos.X <= p1Pos.X + p1Pos.Width
```

this checks for the center of your ball. This will not reflect the ball on its surface but on it's center point.

If that wasn't the strange behaviour you tried to fix, could you please clearify the behaviour you encountered?